# What's a good exercise regime for when traveling/vacationing/etc.?

Tags: running, exercise, p90x, tips, travel

### TL;DR

I'm looking for some input for those of who have an active lifestyle, watch what you eat, try to stay in shape, but also aim to enjoy your time on vacation, as well.

### About Me

I'm a 30 year old male in decent shape (6', 177 lbs). I enjoy running (and have been at it for years - 5ks, 10k, and half-marathons - and continue to run at least three days a week), and the usual home workout programs (like P90X, Insanity, etc.). I've been active with all of the above for the last seven years or so and all's worked well.

I'm married, father of two, am a software developer by day (so I have a relatively sedentary day job), and I know that I can obviously continue exercises like running, push-ups, an so on when I'm out, but I don't have the equipment let alone time to do the usual programs like I do when I'm at home.

### My Main Question(s)

As I've said, I've had a lot of success with all of the above, but questions that I've often had are:

- What are some of the best things to do whenever I'm on vacation?
- What's a good amount of time to allot for said workouts (or should I focus on keeping my heart rate elevated for a period of time)?
- Should I worry too much about skipping days, etc.?
- Any other general tips you guys and girls have?

Though I'm not necessarily concerned with losing a lot of progress over, say, the course of a week, I *am* looking for some suggestions for a regime of sorts of some of the best things that I can do whenever I'm traveling, on vacations, etc., to keep up with the progress I make at home.

I just don't want to be set back that much and the older I get, the easier it seems to become :).

There are a lot of apps available like (like [Freeletics](https://www.freeletics.com/en)) though I've never tried them whenever I'm traveling, but I'm open to things like that, as well so suggestions welcome!

Comment: Unless your accommodation provides a gym, bodyweight and movement-based (such as jogging, running, sprint, jumping, etc) exercises seem like the most available options for you.

Comment: Related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/17820/how-to-eat-healthy-and-maintain-weight-while-travelling-being-on-vacation - Also, I think this is a duplicate, but can't find it at the moment.

Comment: You may find a lot of info re: [exercise and travel](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=travel) in a number of questions.  I like resistance bands - easy to pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What are some of the best things to do whenever I'm on vacation?**

Usually, you should enjoy your vacation, and probably spend some time with your family. With that said, how about doing some sort of **physical activity with your family, such as cycling or hiking**.

**What's a good amount of time to allot for said workouts (or should I focus on keeping my heart rate elevated for a period of time)?**

**1 hour or less should be sufficient.** The reason to that is simple, you don't lose fat or gain muscle through the hours spent on your workout, but rather your diet and your recovery is the one that make the change.

**Should I worry too much about skipping days, etc.?**

**Not at all**, you should spend some of the days doing what you like to do the most or any other activities you would like to try.

**Any other general tips you guys and girls have?**

The most important factor is to **not stress yourself too much about working out**.

As for those applications like Freeletics, I have tried one before, it was [Touchfit:Georges St-Pierre](http://touchfit.com/), but I end up not using it. Instead, ended up making my own routine and did that instead.

**EDIT** :-

Some calisthenics workout :-

[Baristi Beginners Workout](http://baristi-workout.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-calisthenics/)

---> Can't do pull ups? Do a [negative pull ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f3wkcdmVN8) or incline pull ups.

---> Can't do dips? Do bench dips (either with [foot on the floor](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/BWBenchDipFloor.html) or [on another bench](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/BWBenchDip.html)) or more close grip / normal push ups.

[Buff Dude's Punisher Prison BW Workout](http://www.buffdudes.us/blogs/news/25290561-punisher-prison-bodyweight-workout)

---> Can't do one arm push ups? Just do close grip / normal push ups

---> Can't do handstand press? Do [pike push ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sposDXWEB0A)

---> Can't do L-Sits? Do [planks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSHjTRCQxIw) or [hanging leg raises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7g1hxdkulsE), follow the set and seconds provided

[Fortress Beginners Routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-qEE3x27PE)

---> Can't do pull ups? Do a [negative pull ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f3wkcdmVN8) or incline pull ups

---> Can't do a pistol squat? Do your normal squats

---> Can't do handstand hold? Do pike push ups

P.S Inverted Rows = Incline Pull Ups

Comment: > Usually, you should enjoy your vacation, and probably spend some time with your family.

Of course! I'm not talking about going on vacation just to abandon my family and do my own thing :).

This is just something to do in the early morning, while the kids nap, or during the evenings.

Comment: @BobbyHarmless That is good to know C:. Just edited my OP, I included some calisthenics workout which you may want to consider trying.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Aizul! Definitely gonna check 'em out. All of these look completely doable with various things that'll be around.

Answer (score 0):

I try to get at least half of my normal exercise time on vacation. I try to run on treadmills in gyms or outside. The main issue here is the energy that you burn and how that affects your diet and sleep. If you are used to burning something of the order of 1000 Kcal during exercise then stopping with exercising for a prolonged period can cause problems with your eating and sleeping routine.

Answer (score 0):

Go for HIIT exercise which are intense and doesn't require any equipment. The focus is on short burst of high intensity rather than boring long exercises.

One thing people often to forget is that no matter what you do nutrition is the key.If you have got your nutrition right and eat properly then you don't have to worry too much about staying lean. Remember alcohol is known to increase brains sensitivity to smell and taste which results in consuming more fatty and salty food.